# Filtering datasets with two conditions to create a function

Tags: r, filter

This is my dataset. There are **two categorical variables**, `Deciles` (with 10 levels, from `DC1` to `DC10`) and `Population` (with 3 levels: `SAP`, `TD6` and `SH`).

[image]

Hypothetically, each decile (`DC7`, for instance) should have the three levels of `Population` (`SAP`, `TD6` and `SH`), as is the case.

However, some deciles lack one or two `Population` levels (see `DC1` and `DC2`). Important to know is that `SAP` is present in all the deciles, so `TD6` and `SH` are the ones that can be not present.

Now, I want to compare `SAPvsSH`, `SAPvsTD6` and `SHvsTD6`, and I wrote this function which might be further edited and corrected:

```
diff <- function(x) {
  SAP <- sum(x$mean[x$Population == "SAP"])
  SH  <- sum(x$mean[x$Population == "SH"])
  TD6 <- sum(x$mean[x$Population == "TD6"])

  SAPvsSH   <- (SH*100/SAP)-100
  SAPvsTD6  <- (TD6*100/SAP)-100
  SHvsTD6   <- (TD6*100/SH)-100

  show(SAPvsSH)
  show(SAPvsTD6)
  show(SHvsTD6)
}
```

What do I need?

- When comparing `SAPvsSH`, I want to sum all `mean` values of SH, and the `mean` values of `SAP` that are present only in the deciles where `SH` has data. So in this case, it should be `DC7` + `DC8` + `DC9` + `DC10`.
- When comparing `SAPvsTD6`, the same method as before with `SH`.
- When comparing `SHvsTD6`, only deciles where both populations display data should be included.

The last three points are at the beginning of the function.

Later on, in the function, we calculate the percentage error of the second respect the first population. `SAPvsSH` calculates the percentage error of SH respect SAP.

So, how can I introduce the filter of selecting deciles according the presence in `SH` and `TD6`?

Comment: instead of an image, include `dput(your_data)` or if that is big,create a small example in r and use `dput` and include it here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd introduce the filter in the calculation of the percentage error.

Instead of summing up in the beginning, we create subsetted `mean` vectors, which we name by their `Deciles`. Then, when calculating the percentage error, we subset relevant vectors by using the `intersect` of their names (ergo their `Deciles`):

```
FOO <- function(x){
  SAP <- x$mean[x$Population == "SAP"]
  names(SAP) <- x$Deciles[x$Population == "SAP"]
  SH <- x$mean[x$Population == "SH"]
  names(SH) <- x$Deciles[x$Population == "SH"]
  TD6 <- x$mean[x$Population == "TD6"]
  names(TD6) <- x$Deciles[x$Population == "TD6"]

  SAPvsSH <- sum(SH)*100 / sum(SAP[intersect(names(SAP), names(SH))]) - 100
  SAPvsTD6 <- sum(TD6)*100 / sum(SAP[intersect(names(SAP), names(TD6))]) - 100
  SHvsTD6 <- sum(TD6[intersect(names(SH), names(TD6))])*100 / sum(SH[intersect(names(SH), names(TD6))]) - 100
}
```

Comment: Fantastic @LAP. That was exactly what I needed. I correct an error in your code. Thanks.

Comment: Can you edit your code? I cannot... It's in the last line: TD6 instead of TD. Thanks.

Comment: Ah, you are right. Correcting it now. Glad it helped!